# PHP/Curl: How do I display images from an external API?

Tags: php, image, curl

I want to display images from the website "https://picsum.photos/v2/list", however when I try to echo out the url, I get a 404 error. What am I missing from my code?
This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$url = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$picture = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
curl_close($curl);
?>

<?php
  if(!empty($picture)){
    echo 'Picture:';
    foreach($picture as $post){
      echo '<img src= "'. $post["url"] .'" />';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to open this URL in browser's address bar? it doesn't open an image just a page with the image. I cannot be displayed as JPEG then

Comment: I don't see any errors, the code works ok for me. Check your web server logs, you might not have the curl module installed.

Comment: Network inspectors shows, that the URLs leads to `text/html` type of. How could he show the image then?

Comment: You'll want to switch `url` to `download_url`.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks so much, that worked for me! And thank you everyone else for your quick responses, I love this community :) <3

Comment: @smlo1769 if my answer realy help you, then you can upvote my answer, if not then pls don't upvote answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine in my PHP Server but you have one problem that you are using "url" element of array which is url for full page not for single image file.
But There is another element in your api response named "download_url" which return image, so if you change your code to below.

```
<?php
$url = "https://picsum.photos/v2/list";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$picture = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
curl_close($curl);
?>

<?php
  if(!empty($picture)){
    echo 'Picture:';
    foreach($picture as $post){
      echo '<img src= "'. $post["download_url"] .'" />';
    }
  }
?>
```